# Consulta SQL desde android a un API en Laravel usando usando la clausula Like

Tags: php, mysql, android-studio, laravel-5

Estoy realizando una aplicación para android, y mediante un Calendar View selecciono una fecha y tengo que mostrar los registros que comiencen con esa fecha, pero en la base de datos la fecha la guardo con el siguiente formato dd-mm-yyyy H:i:s
y desde la app solo le mando dd-mm-yyyy sin la hora, para eso uso la clausula Like y despues de la fecha un '%' para traer todos los registros que comiencen con la fecha que seleccioné, pero me devuelve nulo y no me da los registros []

```
//codigo en la app
final CalendarView calendarView = (CalendarView) root.findViewById(R.id.calendarViewChido);
    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String fecha = (year + "/"+ month + "/"+ dayOfMonth);

            DateFormat formatoInicial = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");

            String actualdate = "";
            try {
                Date dateInicial = formatoInicial.parse(fecha);
                //* Aqui define el formato deseado.
                String nuevoFormato = "dd-MM-yyyy";

                SimpleDateFormat formatoSalida = new SimpleDateFormat(nuevoFormato);
                actualdate = formatoSalida.format(dateInicial);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            calendarView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            realizarConsulta(actualdate);

        }
    });
public void realizarConsulta(String dateSelected){
    String url = "http://ruta.com/ruta/"+idSensor+"/"+dateSelected;
    GetConection peticion =new GetConection(this,url);
    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), url, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    peticion.execute();

}

//Codigo en el API
public function getByDate($id,$fecha){
    $histDateAll = Temperaturas_sensores::select("id_sensores","valor","date_mx")
        ->where('id_sensores',$id)->Where('date_mx', 'Like', $fecha+'%')
        ->get();
    return $histDateAll;
}
```

Comment: /ruta/{id}/{fecha} tengo de esta manera la ruta

Comment: La columna en la BD es varchar

Comment: De donde viene la referencia Carbon ya que me marca el siguiente error: Carbon' not found

Comment: `\Carbon\Carbon`, pero no sé si te vaya a funcionar. Creo que vas a tener que hacer algún raw con str_to_date o algo así `->whereDate(DB::raw("STR_TO_DATE('date_mx', '%d-%m-%Y')"), \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $fecha))`

Comment: Disculpe las molestias, ya intente de esta manera pero no me funciona

Comment: No es molestia, solo que no tengo un proyecto con una tabla así para probar, pero al ser la columna varchar en vez de date, creo que vas a tener que convertir el dato a DATE para poder hacer la comparación. Te dá algún error la consulta o sólo no te devuelve los datos?